# How to write ResponseBody (in my case PDF) to external storage? Problem with java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I want to write a ResponseBody to external storage(Download folder). Until just a week ago, everything was working perfectly, then I needed to **update the okhttp3 version** and now when I run my application, one of these scenarios happened:

This is my retrofit:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(link)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

This is my function for writing ResponseBody to ES:

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "test.pdf");
    try {
        InputStream fis = body.byteStream();
        long length = body.bytes().length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = fis.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        OutputStream op = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        op.write(bytes);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    return true;
}
```

When i put this part like this:

```
long length = body.bytes().length;
```

I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

But when I leave It like it was before version update:

```
long length = body.contentLength();
```

Then nothing happens. This way was working perfectly until I updated the version of okhttp3.

I know that I can't use the first option with **bytes.length**, but I don't know any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the initialization of the outputstream

```
    OutputStream op;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"test.pdf");
        values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,"application/pdf");
        values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);


        Uri fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                values
        );

        try {
            op = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "test.pdf");
        try {
            op = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        InputStream fis = body.byteStream();
        long length = body.bytes().length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = fis.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }
        
        op.write(bytes);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

Comment: You are right, I just tried on Android Oreo, and It worked perfectly. How can I fix it so it works on the version above Q?

Comment: @Niklaus i rewrote the code in Java. If it works do me a favor and accept the answer.

Comment: File exist in download folder, but when i try to open it, it says "File could not be opened""

Comment: @Niklaus maybe because the file is saved without extension try to save the display name with extension

Comment: Now It works on a real device, It just didn't work on the emulator, but that's ok... Thanks man